# How to protect a local master branch from being rebased?

Tags: git, git-branch, rebase, git-config

I want to protect a specific local branch (e.g. `master`) from being rebased accidentally. I know how to do this on the server side. [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org) has a configuration as shown in the screenshot.

[image: Prevent history rewrite]

How can I protect a local branch (e.g. `master`) from being rebased as in ...?

```
$ git rebase feature master
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go through the following steps:

- add specific setting to your `git config` list with the command:  `git config branch.master.rebaselock true` (along with `master` could be any other branch)
- use `pre-rebase` git hook by Uasi: https://gist.github.com/uasi/9384329

Answer (score 2):

`pre-rebase` hook is what you're after.

Here a quote from https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks:

> **pre-rebase**
>
> This hook is called by git rebase and can be used to prevent a branch from getting rebased. The hook may be called with one or two parameters. The first parameter is the upstream from which the series was forked. The second parameter is the branch being rebased, and is not set when rebasing the current branch.